# Data enumerations (drop down list configurations) Kie Workbench

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, kie, kie-workbench

I am using drools kie workbench 6.4.0 war deployed on wildfly server 8.1.0. I am using guided decision table editor (**GDT editor) to generate compiled .gdst file from the workbench.

To prevent manual typing and potential wrong values being typed, i am using enum classes within the project. Besides i have a mysql database setup on my local system.

Now for example if i have a enum class say City as below in my Kie workbench project

public enum City {

```
LONDAN("londan"),
PARIS("paris");

private String city;

City(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getCityValue() {
    return this.city;
}
```

}

Corresponding to this enum class is a City table in DB with following structure and data

[image]

[image]

If I create a rule using GDT editor which uses the City enum class as column in WHEN clause which will look like

[image]

and the source generated would be like

rule "Row 1 Sample"
    dialect "mvel"
    when
        tp : TransactionProcess( city == City.LONDAN or City.PARIS (based on what i choose as an input either london or paris) )
    then
end

Now the dropdown for city column shows 2 values as it picks it up from the enum class City. My question is how can i make use of City table defined in mysql database to fetch the distinct list of values in city column defined in City table in DB and populate the dropdown for city column in my Sample.gdst file instead of reading the values from an enum class to populate the dropdown.

To summarize i would like to know:

1. How can i enable kie workbench to connect to a datasource.
2. How can i use the datasource to query the database from the workbench and execute a SELECT on a table in DB and use the table column values to populate the dropdown to so that i can choose a value for a column in the WHEN clause of my rule when using GDT editor.

Thanks,

Ashish Sood.

Comment: How many different cities do you have in your DB? Would it be possible to have them all in a single pulldown list in a GUI as you have shown it in your diagram? What will alert you or some program that the DB has been extended, adding one or more cities?

Comment: @laune The City example i have took only to explain my problem. But yes i would like to implement the DB read only for columns whose values i can show in a single pulldown in Kie workbench GUI. That is columns that have limited set of values. What will alert my program that the DB has been changed (update, insert or delete) is a question even i am looking an answer for. Thanks

Comment: Did you every get an answer for this? I am curious if this is built in to the work bench.

Comment: It is possible, please follow the link https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.0.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_drools.advancedenumconcepts